# Merging two ExpressionEngines databases

Tags: database

Just had a client enter a large amount of content (400+ articles) onto our development built by accident, trying to work out a cunning way of merging the live database with the development database without losing any information. Is there any easy ways to do this?

A different editor has also been adding content into the live site so i'm guessing it could get pretty complicated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that all depends on what kind of data was entered. Every fieldtype adds complexity - relationships, Playa, Matrix, Assets, Tag, categories - these all add new rows to additional database tables after the standard `channel_titles` and `channel_data`.

The main thing to worry about is duplicate `entry_id`s. My tactic here is to go through each relevant entry and add a sufficiently-large number to the `entry_id` in every applicable table. So, say your production site has less than 100 new entries since the development database was last synced:

```
UPDATE exp_channel_titles SET entry_id = entry_id + 100 WHERE entry_id IN(<!-- comma-delimited list of the new entry_ids you need to migrate -->)
UPDATE exp_channel_data SET entry_id = entry_id + 100 WHERE entry_id IN(<!-- same list of entry_ids -->)
```

If you have relationships, other complex fieldtypes which use their own table that references the `entry_id` of the entry their data is associated with, you'll need to do work on those as well.

After you've sufficiently incremented all these values, you can merge the DBs.

Comment: Cheers Derek, this looks great, will give it a go!